# Tkinter - bouncing icon script

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a simple bouncing icon program (Python 3.7, Windows 10 x64) to get the feel for Tkinter and canvases. I've posted my code below. My problem with the program is that it clips the edges of the icon (in the direction of motion).  If I slow the motion down a bit (by increasing the value in the after method) it no longer clips, but the motion is choppy. Maybe I'm overthinking this, it basically does what I've aimed for. But if this were a game or other project that mattered, how would this be prevented?

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

xinc, yinc = 5, 5

def load_image(width, height, imgpath):
    loadimg = Image.open(imgpath)
    pwid, phi = loadimg.size
    pf1, pf2 = 1.0*width/pwid, 1.0*height/phi
    pfactor = min([pf1, pf2])
    pwidth, pheight = int(pwid*pfactor), int(phi*pfactor)
    loaded = loadimg.resize((pwidth, pheight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    loaded = ImageTk.PhotoImage(loaded)
    return loaded

def bounce():
    global xinc
    global yinc
    cwid = int(dash.cget('width'))
    chi = int(dash.cget('height'))
    x = dash.coords(dashposition)[0]
    y = dash.coords(dashposition)[1]
    if x > cwid-10 or x < 10:
        xinc = -xinc
    if y > chi-10 or y < 10:
        yinc = -yinc
    dash.move(dashposition, xinc, yinc)
    dash.after(15, bounce)

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='black')

dash = Canvas(root, bg='black', highlightthickness=0, width=400, height=300)
dash.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)

imagepath = os.getcwd() + '/img/cloudy.png'
image = load_image(20, 20, imagepath)

x, y = 10, 10
dashposition = dash.create_image(x, y, anchor=CENTER, image=image, tags=('current'))

bounce()

root.mainloop()
```

[cloudy.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZZRz.png)

Comment: High-speed animation is not what Tkinter is best at.  Pygame might be a better choice here.  (You might be able to speed things up a tiny bit by keeping `cwid`, `chi`, `x`, and `y` in global variables, so you don't have to keep retrieving them from the canvas for each frame.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two contributing factors to the clipping. The main problem is that `load_image(20, 20, imagepath)` will only result in a 20x20 object if the original  image is square. But your cloud object isn't square. And your border collision calculations will only work if the rescaled cloud object is 20x20. So we need to modify that. The other issue is that you aren't compensating for the Canvas's border. The easy way to do that is to set it to zero with `bd=0`.

Its usually a good idea during GUI development to use various colors so you know exactly where your widgets are. So that we can more easily see when the cloud hits the Canvas border I've set the root window color to red. I also increased the `.after` delay, because I just couldn't see what was happening at the speed you set it at. ;) And I made the cloud a bit bigger.

I've made a couple of other minor changes to your code, the main one being that I got rid of that "star" import, which dumps over 100 Tkinter names into your namespace.

#### Update

I've reduced `xinc` & `yinc` to 1, and improved the bounce bounds calculation. (And incorporated jasonharper's suggestion re `cwid` & `chi`). I'm no longer seeing any clipping on my machine, and the motion is smoother. I also reduced the Canvas padding to 1 pixel, but that should have no effect on clipping. I just tried it with `padx=10, pady=10` and it works as expected.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def load_image(width, height, imgpath):
    loadimg = Image.open(imgpath)
    pwid, phi = loadimg.size
    pf1, pf2 = width / pwid, height / phi
    pfactor = min(pf1, pf2)
    pwidth, pheight = int(pwid * pfactor), int(phi * pfactor)
    loaded = loadimg.resize((pwidth, pheight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    loaded = ImageTk.PhotoImage(loaded)
    return loaded, pwidth // 2, pheight // 2

xinc = yinc = 1

def bounce():
    global xinc, yinc

    x, y = dash.coords(dashposition)
    if not bx <= x < cwid-bx:
        xinc = -xinc
    if not by <= y < chi-by:
        yinc = -yinc
    dash.move(dashposition, xinc, yinc)
    dash.after(5, bounce)

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg='red')

dash = tk.Canvas(root, bg='black', 
    highlightthickness=0, width=800, height=600, bd=0)
dash.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
cwid = int(dash.cget('width'))
chi = int(dash.cget('height'))

imagepath = 'cloudy.png'
size = 50
image, bx, by = load_image(size, size, imagepath)
# print(bx, by)

dashposition = dash.create_image(bx * 2, by * 2,
    anchor=tk.CENTER, image=image, tags=('current'))

bounce()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: To accentuate the problem, I took PM 2Ring's code and doubled the canvas size (800 x 600), then reduced the after method delay back to the original 15ms. The clipping is pretty bad this way. Then I took jasonharper's suggestion and moved the chi and cwid lines down to right after the dash.grid call. This had no effect.

Comment: @alanv73 Moving the cwid & chi lines won't affect the clipping, it just improves the efficiency slightly. The only thing that can cause some clipping in my version (apart from the  title bar stuff) is xinc & yinc. Reduce them both to 1. That will slow down the movement, of course.